# Order by members' properties in class

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on a genetic algorithm problem. Suppose I have a `Population()` class that has a list of `Individual()`. Each individual has a score associated with it. What is a good way to order / rank these individuals based their scores in the population? As an example:

```
class Individual(object):
    rr = 100
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = random.randrange(self.rr)

class Population(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.population = [Individual() for _ in xrange(self.size)]

pop = Population(5)
for i in xrange(pop.size):
    print pop.population[i].score
```

Is there a Pythonic way to sort these individuals by their scores? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use the `key` parameter to the `.sort()` method:

```
from operator import attrgetter
pop.population.sort(key=attrgetter('score'))
```

Using [`operator.attrgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) makes this a little easier but is not required.

See the [Sorting Howto](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) on the Python wiki for more tips and tricks.

Comment: Should be getting 'score', not 'rr', but nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted_pop = sorted(pop.population, lambda x, y: cmp(x.score, y.score))
```

Comment: using a cmp function does more work, and the option has been removed from Python 3 (although there is a [workaround](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key)).

Answer (score 0):

Without importing any libraries:

```
pop.population.sort(key=lambda x: x.score)
```